# Sorting Prices from XML

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I am trying to sort the results by prices of an xml with info related to hotels. I want to display and sort the data by prices, given by a value called minCostStay, so ASC and DESC are must to do this.

I am using foreach to display the data endlessly. What I need to do now is sort out these data by price asc and desc. I am pretty much a newbie coding, so any help will be appreciated, specially if it is a simple example =)

This is more or less what I am doing:

```
   $url ="http://www.somedomain.com/cgi/xml/engine/get_data.php?ref=$ref&checkin=$checkin&checkout=$checkout&rval=$rval&pval=$pval&country=$country&city=$city&lg=$lg";


// load SimpleXML
$all = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);

foreach($all as $hotel) // loop through our hotels



{
```

echo <<

```
<table width="100%" border=0>   
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h2><a href="{$hotel->rooms->room->bookUrl}">{$hotel->name}<span class="stars" widht="{$hotel->rating}">{$hotel->rating}</span></h2></a></a>
    <p><b>Direccion:</b> <i>{$hotel->address}</p></i>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle"><div align="center"><a href="{$hotel->rooms->room->bookUrl}"><img src="{$hotel->photoUrl}"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> $rest...<a href="{$hotel->rooms->room->bookUrl}"><strong>ampliar información</strong></a></td>

    <td  colspan="2" valign="middle" align="right"><div align="center">PRECIO: <h3>{$hotel->currencyCode}{$hotel->minCostOfStay}</h3> </a></div></td>

    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center"><a href="{$hotel->rooms->room->bookUrl}"><strong>VER COMENTARIOS, FOTOS Y DETALLES DE ESTE HOTEL</strong></a></div></td>
<td colspan="2"><div align="center">$text</a></div></td>

 </a></div></td>

  </tr>



EOF;


echo '</table>';


}
```

I´m hearing you!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1.Get them from XML (you seem to be able to do that).
2.Put them in an array
3.`sort()` the array, if your items are more complex. possibly using `usort()`:

```
$d =  new SimpleXMLElement('<root>
  <item>
    <price>1234</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <price>4123</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <price>3142</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <price>2431</price>
  </item>
</root>');
$items = array();
foreach($d->item as $item) $items[] = $item;
function _mysort($a,$b){return $a->price - $b->price;}
usort($items,'_mysort');
var_dump($items);
```

Comment: I am getting this:

Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /path on line 315

I am using the following code:
$all = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);


$precio = ($hotel->minCostOfStay);
      
function _mypricesorter($a,$b){
   return $a->minCostOfStay - $b->minCostOfStay;
  
}
sort($precio,'_mypricesorter');  

ideas?

Comment: `$hotel->minCostOfStay` is not an array. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: can we go back to what we had and start from there, I think that method is easier for me. As you can see (info updated in the question), am alredy using a foreach and I am not sure on how to use a foreach inside a foreach.. It is possible?

Comment: Ok Wrikken, your example works. Thing is how do I extract the info out from the XML and write it where the <root><item><price>1234</price></item> is?

Answer (score 1):

I recently disocvered SimpleDOM for a project where I needed a more advanced xpath system.  I really like it and I think it could do what you're looking for.  You can find it (docs are bundled in the source code download) here: http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/

You'll want to look at the sortedXPath() method I believe:

```
sortedXPath (line 888)

Run an XPath query and sort the result

This method accepts any number of arguments in a way similar to array_multisort()

   1. // Retrieve all <x/> nodes, sorted by @foo ascending, @bar descending
   2. $root->sortedXPath('//x', '@foo', '@bar', SORT_DESC);
   3. 
   4. // Same, but sort @foo numerically and @bar as strings
   5. $root->sortedXPath('//x', '@foo', SORT_NUMERIC, '@bar', SORT_STRING, SORT_DESC);

    * access: public

void sortedXPath (string $xpath)

    * string $xpath: XPath expression
```